# Checking assumptions for random effects in nested mixed-effects models in R / S-Plus

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, error-message

I am modelling a nested mixed-effects model with just the intercept in the random part, of the form:

```
fit4<-lme(fixed = Stdquad~factor(LayoutN)+factor(nCHIPS.fixed), random = ~1|Class.Ordered/student)
```

When trying to check the assumption on the independent, identically distributed (iid) random effects in SPlus using `ranef()`, I keep getting the error:

```
Problem in sort.list: ordering not defined for mode "list": sort.list(x, partial)
```

I suspect the nesting is the problem since if I remove *student*, the plots come up fine.

I would like to know how I can check that the random effects are iid and are independent for different groups using S-Plus (or R since its very similar).

Comment: R and S-Plus are very similar, but definitely not the same (I know from painful experience!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are using the `nlme` package. Maybe it would be worth trying R and the `lme4` instead, although it is not fully comparable wrt. syntax or function call.

In your case, I would suggest to specify the `level` when you called `ranef()`, see `?ranef.lme`:

```
   level: an optional vector of positive integers giving the levels of
          grouping to be used in extracting the random effects from an
          object with multiple nested grouping levels. Defaults to all
          levels of grouping.
```

This is also present in the official [documentation](http://ftp.chg.ru/pub/math/NLME/UGuide.pdf) for NLME 3.0 (e.g., p. 17).

Check out Douglas Bates's neat handouts on GLMM. He is also writing a textbook entitled *lme4: Mixed-effects modeling with R*. All are available on [R-forge](http://lme4.R-forge.R-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks. It worked - this way I can plot both the Class random effects (level=1), and the student (level=2).